# Данные для создания ЭЦП

Tags: облако

Не уверен что тут найдется человек хорошо знающий ЭЦП, но все же. Может кто подскажет что значат ниже приведенные переменные которые указываются при создании облачной ЭЦП?

```
1) DN – Требуемый Subject в сертификате;

2) EKU – список требуемых OID-ов через запятую в поле Улучшенный ключ;

3) AltName – Альтернативное имя;

4) KeySpec – Использование ключа;
```

Answer (score 4):

Для ответа на Ваш вопрос никакие хорошие знания ЭЦП не нужны.
Достаточно знать что лежит в основе этих ЭЦП и небольшое умение гуглить.
http://pro-ldap.ru/tr/zytrax/tech/ssl.html#x509
Там кажется есть описание всех переменных из вопроса. Причём на русском языке. Что просто невероятно!